# Wordpress homepage Custom Post types pagination 404

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I use the following code to display my custom post types:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

<?php //query_posts('paged='.$paged);

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('&posts_per_page=1'.'&paged='.$paged.'&post_type=blogpost&meta_key=category&meta_value='.$tempcat);
?>
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<div>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<div id="navigation">
                <div id="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
                <div id="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

This code works fine with every page, exept the homepage. Whenever i click the next posts links i'm redirected to a 404 page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

change your query to:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('cat=&paged=' . $paged);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in "wordpress query post". if you want to know more read [Function Reference/query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).. and now try this code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('cat=&paged=' . $paged);
?>
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<div>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div id="navigation">
<div id="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
<div id="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

good luck